# Ansible map item with different value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How can I map each user (item) with a specific rsa key using ansible? I want to map the public key for each user.

For example, for each user I need to map different keys.

```
authorized_key:
    user: "paul"
    key: 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA'
    user: "rob"
    key: 'ssh-rsa AAAA123465A'
```

Here is the complete playbook:

```
---
- name: Create Users
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars:
    users:
    - "paul"
    - "rob"
    - "ruby"

  tasks:
  - name: "Create user accounts"
    user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
    with_items: "{{ users }}"

  - name: "Add authorized keys"
    authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item }}"
        key: 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA'
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Comment: Does dictionaries work? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=ansible%20doc#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name

Comment: Dict should work, but I'm not sure how it should be. Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define variables as list, not as dictionary:

```yaml
---
- name: Create Users
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users_list:
     - user: "paul"
       key: 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA'
     - user: "rob"
       key: 'ssh-rsa AAAA123465A'
  tasks:
  - name: "Create user accounts"
    user:
        name: "{{ item.user }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
    with_items: "{{ users_list }}"

  - name: "Add authorized keys"
    authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item.user }}"
        key: '{{ item.key }}'
    with_items: "{{ users_list }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a more straightforward structure for this purpose. Add the below declarations into the *vars*

```yaml
    users: [paul, rob, ruby]
    authorized_key_users: "{{ authorized_key.keys()|list }}"
    authorized_key:
      paul: |-
        ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA admin@srv1
      rob: |-
        ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2
```

Then, the iterations are very simple

```yaml
     - debug:
         msg: "Create user {{ item }}"
       loop: "{{ users }}"
     - debug:
         msg: |
           For {{ item }} add authorized key:
           {{ authorized_key[item] }}
       loop: "{{ users }}"
       when: item in authorized_key_users
```

give

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=paul) => 
  msg: Create user paul
ok: [localhost] => (item=rob) => 
  msg: Create user rob
ok: [localhost] => (item=ruby) => 
  msg: Create user ruby

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
k: [localhost] => (item=paul) => 
  msg: |-
    For paul add authorized key:
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA admin@srv1
ok: [localhost] => (item=rob) => 
  msg: |-
    For rob add authorized key:
    ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2
skipping: [localhost] => (item=ruby)
```

---

The structure can be simplified further by putting the public keys into a standalone dictionary. This will be very useful if a user has more authorized keys. For example, put the below declarations into the vars

```yaml
    users: [paul, rob, ruby]
    authorized_key_users: "{{ authorized_key.keys()|list }}"
    authorized_key:
      paul:
        - admin@srv1
        - admin@srv2
      rob:
        - admin@srv2
    public_key:
      admin@srv1: |-
        ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA admin@srv1
      admin@srv2: |-
        ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2
```

Then, the iterations below simplify also the case with multiple keys

```yaml
     - debug:
         msg: "Create user {{ item }}"
       loop: "{{ users }}"
     - debug:
         msg: |
           For {{ item }} add authorized keys:
           {% for key in authorized_key[item] %}
           {{ public_key[key] }}
           {% endfor %}
       loop: "{{ users }}"
       when: item in authorized_key_users
```

give

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=paul) => 
  msg: Create user paul
ok: [localhost] => (item=rob) => 
  msg: Create user rob
ok: [localhost] => (item=ruby) => 
  msg: Create user ruby

TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=paul) => 
  msg: |-
    For paul add authorized keys:
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA admin@srv1
    ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2
ok: [localhost] => (item=rob) => 
  msg: |-
    For rob add authorized keys:
    ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2
skipping: [localhost] => (item=ruby)
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    users: [user1, user2, admin]
    authorized_key_users: "{{ authorized_key.keys()|list }}"
    authorized_key:
      user1:
        - admin@srv1
        - admin@srv2
      user2:
        - admin@srv2
    public_key:
      admin@srv1: |-
        ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA admin@srv1
      admin@srv2: |-
        ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2

  tasks:
    - name: Create user accounts
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
      loop: "{{ users }}"
    - name: Add authorized keys
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item }}"
        key: |
          {% for key in authorized_key[item] %}
          {{ public_key[key] }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when: item in authorized_key_users
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml -CD

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Create user accounts] ******************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=user1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=user2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=admin)

TASK [Add authorized keys] *******************************************************************
--- before: /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys
+++ after: /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA admin@srv1
+ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2

changed: [localhost] => (item=user1)
--- before: /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys
+++ after: /home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+ssh-rsa AAAA123465AAAAA123 admin@srv2

changed: [localhost] => (item=user2)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=admin) 

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```